# Why does Celery task autodiscovery never trigger under Django?

Tags: django, celery, autodiscovery

Everything is working except task autodiscovery under Django.  (Celery 5.2.6, Django 3.0.6)

If I run `celery worker`, the worker triggers autodiscovery, finds all my tasks, and displays them in a list as part of it's startup process.  However, if I run my Django app or Django shell, this never happens.

Additionally, even though [the docs promise](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.tasks) that accessing the task registry will trigger autodiscovery, it does not.  I print `app.tasks`, I call `app.tasks.keys()`, and still no autodiscovery - it only shows the tasks that are built-in or were registered when the module containing them happened to be imported for other reasons.

What do I need to do to trigger task autodiscovery?

PS - If I try adding `force=True` to `app.autodiscover_tasks()`, it fails because the Django app registry hasn't finished loading at that time.

Answer (score -1):

I dug into the code and tried a bunch of things.  Here's what I learned.

**How Autodiscovery is Performed**

Autodiscovery is actually performed by `app._autodiscover_tasks()` ([src](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.6/celery/app/base.py#L686)), which is invoked by the `celery.signals.import_modules` signal ([src](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.6/celery/signals.py#L106)), which is sent by `app.loader.import_default_modules()` ([src](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.6/celery/loaders/base.py#L99)).  The signal is connected to `app._autodiscover_tasks()` in `app.autodiscover_tasks` ([src](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.6/celery/app/base.py#L682)).

In other words, the only way to get autodiscovery to trigger is to:

1. call `app.autodiscover_tasks()` to register `app._autodiscover_tasks` as a receiver for signal `celery.signals.import_modules`
2. call `app.loader.import_default_modules()` to send the signal

The docs instruct me to do the first, but not the second.  Thus, in my Django app, autodiscovery does not happen.

**How Autodiscovery is Performed in `celery`**

If you run `celery` with the commands [beat](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.6/celery/apps/beat.py#L124), [report](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.6/celery/bin/celery.py#L161), [shell](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.6/celery/bin/shell.py#L137), or [worker](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.6/celery/concurrency/prefork.py#L53), the resulting code path eventually calls `app.loader.import_default_modules()` directly.  Thus, autodiscovery happens under those conditions - but not when you run your Django app, or open a Django shell, or any other context but those four commands, unless you explicitly call `app.loader.import_default_modules()`.

**On Finalize**

The docs promise that accessing `app.tasks` will cause the app to finalize, which I assumed triggered autodiscovery, but it has nothing to do with that.  All that [finalize](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.2.6/celery/app/base.py#L517) does is send an `app.on_after_finalize` signal, which does nothing.

**My Solution**

After much frustrating and experimentation, I settled on this snippet from my `celery.py`:

```
app = Celery("myproj")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.on_after_configure.connect()
def trigger_autodiscovery(sender, **kwargs):
    app.loader.import_default_modules()
```